# Script compilation take a too long time

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server

when write data into janusgraph, there are many WARN level logs in gremlin-server.log file.

most of the WARN logs look like this:

```
2020-09-09 21:41:56,181 WARN  [gremlin-server-exec-11] GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:830 - Script compilation g.V(20297120).as('from').V(21106840).as('to').addE('HAS_INF').from('from').to('to') took 38059ms
```

why compiling such a simple script takes so long time ?

Is there someone can give me some hints to improve the script compilation time or tell me how to analyze the causes?

working enviroment:

janusgraph version: 0.5.2

backend storage: cassandra,version:3.11

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what the problem is. You may need to profile your server a bit to get to the bottom of it, but my guess is that the server is seeing some heavy usage during your writes and perhaps some threads in your `gremlinPool` are slowed as a result. `gremlin-server-exec-*` threads are responsible for script compilation and execution, so I could imagine a situation where an overloaded server appeared to take a really long time to do a compilation on a quite small script. I would check your resource utilization on that server to see what the real problem is though that is triggering these WARN messages as I sense it isn't related to the actual compilation time of the script.

Script compilation problems usually show themselves with massive scripts or an excessive number of variables. Since you don't have that situation, I think it points to other issues.

The first issue I would consider without even looking at the server configuration is to look at the scripts you are sending when you see these WARNs. I could be wrong, but from the log message it appears that you aren't parameterizing at all. If that is the case, you are going to end up with much heavier resource usage on the server with much slower performance because every single request will likely need to be compiled. That situation also bloats the compile script cache. If you are not parameterizing, you should look to do so and you will be impressed by the performance improvement when you do. Documentation for it is found [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#parameterized-scripts).

If you are parameterizing, then I can only again offer that you profile the server to find the root cause of the problem, as it shouldn't be related to script length as the log message might imply.